# How to effectively convert double to int in c++?

Tags: c++

Sorry for not being specific, I just thought the context isn't important.

Anyway the question can be seen as an extension of my other question on [Progressbars in win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000715/progressbar-range-and-position-how-to-handle-big-numbers-in-c) should I put the whole code here or the link is enough ?

The problem in its simplest form can be described as :

```
double d1 = x.xxxxxx;
double d2 = x.xxxxxx;
double d3 = x.xxxxxx;
double d4 = x.xxxxxx;
double d5 = x.xxxxxx;
...
...
double dn = x.xxxxxx;


int i1 = (int)d1;
int i2 = (int)d2;
int i3 = (int)d3;
int i4 = (int)d4;
int i5 = (int)d5;
...
...
int in = (int)dn;

int i = i1+i2+i3+i4+i5+...+in;
double d = d1+d2+d3+d4+d5+...+in;

now i needs to be not less then d - 0.5;
```

How to do that ?

EDIT : Code modified.
EDIT 2 : The number of n can not be predicted, and it is possible that d1,d2,...,dn are less then 1, something like, 0.345627.

Comment: Sum up the doubles and convert as the last step?! (Add `0.5` before converting.)

Comment: C converts by truncation rather than rounding, so that won't quite work.  `math.h` has a `round` function that should work, though.

Comment: @KerrekSB that's not possible in the scenerio that presents the problem.

Comment: `(int) (d + 0.5)` will work _provided that `d` is >= -0.5_.

Comment: OK, in that case, multiply all the ints by a gazillion, sum them up, and then divide by a gazillion again.

Comment: `i = i1+i2+i3+i4+i5+5` satisfies the condition. So does `i = i1+i2+i3+i4+i5+666`. This question is just a bit silly. Please could you ask the real question.

Comment: I'm still confused as to what the goal is here.  There are a variety of ways to round `double`s up, down, toward 0, away from 0, and to nearest integers.  What are the full requirements on `i1`, `i2`, `i3`, `i4`, and `i5`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are interested in is error diffusion:

```
double d1 = x.xxxxxx;
double d2 = x.xxxxxx;
double d3 = x.xxxxxx;
double d4 = x.xxxxxx;
double d5 = x.xxxxxx;

double error = 0;
int i1 = (int)floor(d1+error+0.5);
error += d1-i1;
int i2 = (int)floor(d2+error+0.5);
error += d2-i2;
int i3 = (int)floor(d3+error+0.5);
error += d3-i3;
int i4 = (int)floor(d4+error+0.5);
error += d4-i4;
int i5 = (int)floor(d5+error+0.5);

int i = i1+i2+i3+i4+i5;
double d = d1+d2+d3+d4+d5;
```

Each time you round the value, you see how much error is introduced, and propagate a correction to the next calculation.  This way, your error can never build up.

Comment: You think the intent is to implement or analyze some version of [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm)?

Comment: @JoshuaGreen: Yes, it seems very similar.

Comment: @JoshuaGreen: The problem that the OP is expressing is due to accumulated rounding error, which can be addressed as I described.  Kahan summation is addressing the problem of rounding due to the lack of precision of the floating point representation.  I'm addressing the problem of rounding due to the lack of precision of an integer.

Comment: @VaughnCato Seems like the best answer to what I am looking for but the final result still isn't coming out as I hoped, its close, like: i == 90% of d.

Comment: @VaughnCato If I correctly understand it, suppose : error = 0; d1 = 0.3; i = floor( 0.3 + error + 0.5 ) = floor(0.8) = 1, error = -0.7, d2 = 0.1, i = floor( 0.1 - 0.7 + 0.5 ) = floor(-0.1) = -1; Wouldn't it affect the final outcome at the end particularly when number of times we have to repeat it is pretty large, What you say ?

Comment: @StudentX: I haven't found a case where i < d-0.5.

Comment: @StudentX: I'm not sure what you mean by affecting the final outcome.  Are you saying that using this approach would cause i to come out to a different value than if you didn't use it?

Comment: @VaughnCato thanks, worked perfect. Sorry for the confusion. :)

Answer (score 1):

> now i needs to be not less then d - 0.5;

This can be achieved easily by rounding the doubles up (cast to int will round them towards 0).

As Josua Green says, this can be done with `(int)(d + 0.5)` (if d>-0.5), or `std::ceil()` if you prefer.

Comment: Cast to `int` will round them _toward 0_.

Answer (score 1):

Converting to an int truncates the double: i.e. drops any fraction bit.

By adding 0.5 to  positive numbers and -0.5 to negative numbers, we get the more conventional behaviour.

```
int ToInt(double x)
{
   double dx = x < 0.0 ? -0.5 : 0.5;
   return static_cast<int>(x + dx);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sum up the doubles:

```
double d = d1+d2+d3+d4+d5;
```

Check that the sum of doubles doesn't exceed the integer conversion by more than 0.5

```
if (d - (int)d > 0.5) { /* Error? */ }
```